# tengo una aplicacion movil en la cual quiero usar un boton para volver a una vista personalizada dependiendo si es un administrador o un director

Tags: android-studio

al ejetucar este metodo mi boton no hace nada en el bundle extaigo mi valor tipo el cual es el que quiero usar para que mi boton me regrese a mi vista anterior dependiendo de su valor

```
Bundle bundle1=this.getIntent().getExtras();

        if(bundle1!=null){
            tipo1=bundle1.getString("tipo");
            txttipo.setText(tipo1);
        }

        volver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                volver();
            }
        });

public void volver(){

            if(tipo1 != null && tipo1.equalsIgnoreCase("Director")){
                Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Director.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            if(tipo1 != null && tipo1.equalsIgnoreCase("Administrador")){
                Intent intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Administrador.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
    }
```

Comment: Revisa lo que comento en mi respuesta, si no funciona agrega como envías la información.

Comment: de hecho todo el bundle hasta donde empieza el metodo es codigo que va dentro del oncreate no lo puse todo completo por que mi oncreate lleva demasiado codigo aparte, muchas gracias por contestar

Answer (score 0):

Si no esta realizando nada tu programa primero debes revisar si en verdad recibes el valor. Es demasiado importante asegures que los datos que envías se reciban dentro de `onCreate()` de otra forma obtendrás valores null:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Recibe datos...
    Bundle bundle1=this.getIntent().getExtras();

    if(bundle1!=null){
        tipo1=bundle1.getString("tipo");
        txttipo.setText(tipo1);
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```